# Thymeleaf fragment cannot be resolved when passing as variable i.e. <div th:replace="${page}">

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am build a web app with sping mvc 4.2.2 and thymeleaf-spring4 2.1.2 and most of the pages share the same header, sidebar, etc. Because of that I decided to have only one `view` (.html) which replaces a child `div` depends on a parameter `page` from the url.

The page name will be translated to fragment name by the Controller:

```
//SpringTestHello.java
@Controller
public class SpringTestHello {      
    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String testMap(@RequestParam(value="page", required=false, defaultValue="overview") String page, Model model) {
        if (page.equalsIgnoreCase("overview"))
            page = "overview :: overview";
        if (page.equalsIgnoreCase("user"))
            page = "overview :: user";
        model.addAttribute("page", page);       
        return "main_page";
    }
}
```

And the main page will replace a child div with the `page` attribute:

```
<!--main_page.html-->
<div id="pageContent" th:if="${!page.isEmpty()}" 
    th:replace="${page}">Main Content here</div>
<!--This causes exception-->
```

However this results in TemplateInputException:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: 
Error resolving template "overview :: overview", template might not exist or might not be
accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers (main_page:123)
```

while using string literal works as expected:

```
<!--main_page.html-->
<div id="pageContent" th:replace="overview :: overview"></div>
<!--This shows the correct fragment-->
```

Why is it unable to resolve the template when the fragment name is passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pre-process ([See Docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing)) `${page}` in your replace statement so that it happens before any other processing, which allows the fragment to be included properly.

Your replace would become (note the double underscores surrounding `${page}`):

```
<div id="pageContent" th:if="${!page.isEmpty()}"
    th:replace="__${page}__">Main Content here</div>
```

I'd also suggest you take a look at the [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect) which is very suited to your current use case -- decorating different pages with some standard content.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks! I'm also going to switch to layout dialect after reading about it